# Magento minimum order amount not working correctly

Tags: magento, error-handling, magento-1.7

We have set in one of our shops a minimum amount of 4. When we place products less then this amount in our shopping cart we get the error message showing up like 10 times and after that you can not visit the shopping cart. There is a fatal error and the webpage is giving the message that there are to many loops.

Does anyone has a fix?

Kind regards

Comment: More context please, what fatal error, message, etc.. Also what have *you* tried

Comment: Please be more specific.